# Divider help (PHP, Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, menu, divider

Having a strange issue with my PHP walker in Wordpress. My menu is acting up and CSS won't fix my issue.

Its doing `| HOME | ABOUT | NEWS | FAQ`

It should be `HOME | ABOUT | NEWS | FAQ`

Here is my walker code. What am I doing wrong?

```
class top_bar_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

  function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {
    $element->has_children = !empty( $children_elements[$element->ID] );
    $element->classes[] = ( $element->current || $element->current_item_ancestor ) ? 'active' : '';
    $element->classes[] = ( $element->has_children ) ? 'has-dropdown not-click' : '';

parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
  }

  function start_el( &$output, $object, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0 ) {
      $item_html = '';
      parent::start_el( $item_html, $object, $depth, $args ); 

      $output .= ( $depth == 0 ) ? '<li class="divider"></li>' : '';

      $classes = empty( $object->classes ) ? array() : (array) $object->classes;  

      if( in_array('label', $classes) ) {
          $output .= '<li class="divider"></li>';
          $item_html = preg_replace( '/<a[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/iU', '<label>$1</label>', $item_html );
      }
  if ( in_array('divider', $classes) ) {
      $item_html = preg_replace( '/<a[^>]*>( .* )<\/a>/iU', '', $item_html );
  }
  $output .= $item_html;
  }
  function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
      $output .= "\n<ul class=\"sub-menu dropdown\">\n";
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class top_bar_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
        static $count=1;
      function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {
        $element->has_children = !empty( $children_elements[$element->ID] );
        $element->classes[] = ( $element->current || $element->current_item_ancestor ) ? 'active' : '';
        $element->classes[] = ( $element->has_children ) ? 'has-dropdown not-click' : '';

    parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
      }

      function start_el( &$output, $object, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0 ) {
          $item_html = '';
          parent::start_el( $item_html, $object, $depth, $args ); 

          $output .= ( self::$count > 1 ) ? '<li class="divider"></li>' : '';

          $classes = empty( $object->classes ) ? array() : (array) $object->classes;  

          if( in_array('label', $classes) ) {
              $output .= '<li class="divider"></li>';
              $item_html = preg_replace( '/<a[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/iU', '<label>$1</label>', $item_html );
          }
      if ( in_array('divider', $classes) ) {
          $item_html = preg_replace( '/<a[^>]*>( .* )<\/a>/iU', '', $item_html );
      }
      $output .= $item_html;
      self::$count++;  // increase counter
      }
      function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
          $output .= "\n<ul class=\"sub-menu dropdown\">\n";
      } 
    }
```

Depth is used only for traversing child items, it is not an iterated counter.

Comment: I see what you did. Clever! Unfortunately it does not show any dividers now, not even in source. Trying to edit what you have to see what I can get working. Is there a quick fix up? Thank you so much by the way!

Comment: Corrected my code, changed `$output .= ( $count > 1 )` to `$output .= ( self::$count > 1 )`

Comment: This worked brilliantly. Thank you very much! Answer has been approved :D